# Failing to connect trough SFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, sftp

I have a VPS with Ubuntu18 with vsftp installed. And I have a client-side MacBook HighSierra.

Just recently installed the VPS, and since I'm new to networking I used [this](https://chubbable.com/build-a-virtual-private-server-using-ubuntu-14-04#vps-setup-and-configuration) tutorial to configured it - except TCP wrapper and fail2ban, that I will take care in the end. I access my server by using SSH with pubkey authentication.

Now I need to access FTP so I've installed vsftp on the server following [this](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ftp-server-in-ubuntu/) tutorial. I'm able to use FTP from the server, but not from the client machine (my Mac). I learned that HighSierra required SFTP (because it's more secure than FTP) but not working either.

So my open ports from `ufw status` are:

```
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file looks like this (note that I have a 'my-user' user, and a 'my-userftp' user):

```
Port 22
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
X11Forwarding no
PrintMotd no
UseDNS no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
PermitRootLogin no

AllowUsers my-user*

Match Group sftp_users
ChrootDirectory /home/my-userftp/
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

And here is my `/etc/vsftpd.config`:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist

userlist_deny=NO

tcp_wrappers=YES

user_sub_token=$USER

local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
```

and `/etc/vsftpd.userlist` has only "my-userftp" written.

Finally, I have two users on my system: my-user (sudoer for general control) and my-userftp (specific for file transfer, from sftp_users group). My folder structure from `/home/my-userftp` is:

```
total 12
4 dr-xr-xr-x 3 nobody  nogroup    4096 Dec 21 13:19 ftp
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 my-userftp sftp_users 4096 Dec 21 15:37 sftp
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root    root        130 Dec 20 19:09 steps
```

Trying to access through FileZilla using the configuration (SFTP protocol, my-userftp, userpassword, port 22) I get the error:

```
Status:         Connecting to x.x.x.x...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    open "my-userftp@x.x.x.x" 22
Command:    Trust new Host-key: Once
Command:    Pass: *************
Error:          Connection reset by peer
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

Then using AuthKey in FileZilla:

```
Status:         Connecting to x.x.x.x...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    keyfile "/Users/user/Documents/id_rsa_filezilla.ppk"
Command:    open "my-userftp@.x.x.x" 22
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Command:    Pass: 
Error:          Authentication failed.
Error:          Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

And thought terminal (on Mac) it gives me:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

What could be going wrong and how can I solve it? Hope I gave enough info. I'm not very experienced in system networking, though I'm learning. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"I learned that HighSierra required SFTP"* - I do not believe that HighSierra  is blocking **outgoing** FTP connections. It's blocking **incoming** connections only - so this is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Check your logs on your server.

Comment: What are the permissions of `ChrootDirectory /home/my-userftp/` when you use  `ls -l /home/my-userftp` ?  Also what is this `AllowUsers my-user*`?  Why not just `AllowUsers my-user` ? Also who is the owner of `/home/my-userftp` directory?